# (Graded) deformations of algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

I'm reading the article of Braverman and Gaitsgory, *Poincaré-Birkhoff-Witt theorem for quadratic algebras of Koszul type*, but I'm stuck in a point near the beginning.

Let $A$ be a (positively) graded associative algebra over a field $k$. They define the groupoid of i-th level graded deformation of $A$ to be the category $\mathcal E_i(A)$, whose objects are graded $k[t]/(t^{i+1})$-algebras $B$, free over $k[t]/(t^{i+1})$ with an isomorphism $B / t B \simeq A$ and whose morphisms are isomorphisms of such objects.

This is the classical definition of deformation (of whatever algebro-geometric object) and I have no doubt about it. Moreover, it is clear that reduction modulo $t^i$ defines a functor $\mathcal F_i \colon \mathcal E_{i+1}(A) \to \mathcal E_i(A)$.

Now, they define $\mathcal E(A)$ to be the groupoid of graded algebras $B$ over $k[t]$ (yes, the polynomial ring), free over $k[t]$, together with an isomorphism $B / t B \simeq A$, and they claim the following:

**Lemma.** Reductions modulo $t^i$ define an equivalence between the category $\mathcal E(A)$ and the inverse limit of the categories $\mathcal E_i(A)$ with respect to the functors $\mathcal F_i$.

This looks false to me: I should be able to prove the statement if we replace the groupoid $\mathcal E(A)$ with the groupoid of deformations over the formal power series ring $k[[t]]$, but I don't see how to pass from a deformation over $\mathrm{Spec}(k[[t]])$ to a deformation over the affine line $\mathrm{Spec}(k[t])$.

**Remark 1.** They use this property in what follows, because the strategy of the proof is precisely to construct a suitable deformation and then taking its fiber over $1$. However, as far as I understand, what they really do is to show that koszulity and certain conditions imply that the algebra $A$ we are interested in is unobstructed, so that we can construct a deformation over $\mathrm{Spec}(k[[t]])$.

**Remark 2.** They say that this machinery can be essentially found in the classical work of Gerstenhaber, *On the deformation of rings and algebras*. I gave it a look, but it doesn't seem to consider deformations which are not infinitesimal, i.e. deformations over the affine line (just over formal power series rings). However, I could be wrong here, for I haven't read the whole article of Gerstenhaber.

Comment: I cannot provide a clear-cut answer, but I think the missing ingredient is the grading. (By the way, graded deformations and $i$-th level graded deformations have to be free as **graded** modules over $k\left[t\right]$, resp. $k\left[t\right] / k\left[t\right]t^{i+1}$, not just as modules.) If you have a sequence of $i$-th level graded deformations $A_i$ of $A$ which are obtained from each other using the reduction functors, then you can identify their bases (by iterated lifting, probably using the axiom of choice) and define their inverse limit as the free graded $k\left[t\right]$-module ...

Comment: ... on that basis, with the product defined compatibly with the reduction functors (this determines the product uniquely, because in order to compute $ab$ for given $a$ and $b$ in the inverse limit, you only need to know the residue class of $ab$ modulo $t^j$ for a sufficiently high $j$, **thanks to the gradedness of this $k\left[t\right]$-module**). So you get a graded deformation of $A$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think I'm understanding what you are saying. If $M_i$ is the family of deformations, first we use the freeness to get a (free) $k[t]$-module $M$ such that $M/t^iM \simeq M_i$; then we use gradedness to define (uniquely) the product. I'm almost there, I simply need to think a bit more!
(In fact, I was totally ignoring both freeness and gradedness, and the result is then arguably false, I believe).